# How do you calculate pixel size of string?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a string. I know the font family and the font size it is going to be displayed in. I need to know how many pixels the text will take up in the ui. So that I can determine whether to show another element. How would I do that?

I found a couple of things, but none of them were available in my Windows universal project. For example:

- [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)
- [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx)

Edit:

This is not a web project.

I want to calculate the size it will take in the ui before it is in the ui.

Comment: Is the class [`FormattedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) allowed in a universal project? That is how you do it for WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to create  a `textblock` in code and assign the desired text to it. Then you can get the actual height and width from it. See the below code

```
         TextBlock txt=new TextBlock();
        //set additional properties of textblock here . Such as font size,font family, width etc.
        txt.Text = "your text here";
        var height = txt.ActualHeight;
        var width = txt.ActualWidth;
```

You can do further operations based on this height and width

I am not saying this is the optimized solution .But this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the values of the `Width` and `Height` properties of the control you use to display your text (eg. your `TextBox`), after setting your string as text/content, to decide whether to show another element.

Comment: But what if I want to calculate it before displaying it.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but try the answer in the `Loaded` event handler of your page.

Comment: But I don't want to calculate it based on ui elements. I want to calculate it from the string. Calculating it based on the ui element will not work in my case.